# Best practice (forward compatibility) for theme options

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options

So here is what I'm wondering...

You all know about Option-tree and similar frameworks that theme authors are using for their theme option pages. You also all know that since 3.4 WordPress introduced their Customization API. Obviously they will want theme authors to use it instead of the frameworks metnioned. And obviously this will be the good way, since it's native.

However, their is one issue... WP Customizer doesn't provide enough space. Imagine you have options such as these:

[image]

I can think of a way to import all of them into the Customizer... that also goes for social links, layout options, background pattern options and so on...

One way I can think of is creating separate admin pages for these... but if you get that approach chances are that you will end up with few different pages for your options.. and that will surely confuse guys using your theme.

So what we should do?

Please, let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If space were the only problem you could simply enqueue a css file to the admin area with these lines to expand the width of the customizer panel from the usual 300px to 500px:

```
.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {width 500px !important;}
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {margin-left:500px !important;}
```

Hey, you could even enqueue a js file to insert a button to toggle between different widths. The customizer API is flexible enough to contain all fields you would want. So, space really is not the big issue.

The real issue is what to incorporate in the customizer and how to organize it. Read, for instance, [this excellent overview](http://maddisondesigns.com/2015/06/lets-talk-about-the-wordpress-customizer/) by Anthony Hortin. Theme developers should study which of their options are best for their clients to address in the customizer and which should remain on option pages.